# Updating field values of duplicate arrays using powershell

Tags: powershell

Below is my input array

```
Store,hotel,cafe,bar, number
111,true, true, true,02
111, false, false, true,09
112, true, false,true,08
112, true, false,false,06
113, true, false, true,05
```

Expected output

```
Store, hotel,cafe,bar, number
111, true, true, true, 02
111, true, true, true,09
112, true, false, true, 08
112, true, false, true, 06
113, true, false, true,05
```

My Code

```
$testarray = import-csv -path "C:directory\ocb2021\preprocessings.csv"

foreach($member in $testarray)
{
  if(($testarray -match $member.store).count -gt 1)
  {
    write-host  "match found"

    $success = $member.store | where $member.bar -eq 'true'
  }
}
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about. Please, start with the [tour] and read [ask]! Then, describe what you did, what results you got, what you expected and why.

Comment: Edited my post with  details of input array and expected output

Comment: Okay, and what code have you written? You might also want to tag this with the used interpreter (MS Powershell) to get better visibility.

Comment: added the code i have tried . Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format it using backticks. Also, what is the output you got? Please read those links I provided as well, these basics are described there!

Comment: This CSV file has above 2000 entries . In which value in the field store will be repeated in some cases it will not repeat. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't get any output yet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear what you are trying to do, but there are a few elementary issues in your code:

1. you did not initialize the $Success to $false, if you run the script multiple times in the same powershell session with different inputs, as soon as one succeeds, ALL will return success. Powershell variables exist for the session, not just the run of the script. Not sure how this variable fits into your objectives however.
2. $member.Store is the Store property of the $Member object, you then pipe this and check $Member.bar, however this is not doing what you expect, it is taking the **value** of $member.bar and using that as the property **name** so in fact it is looking for the "store" (string) to have a property named true or false (row dependent), and then is determining if that property is true or false.
3. in addition a Where will either return the **object** or not, so $Success is either the object or null not true/false. In certain places this can be implicitly treated as a true/false (e.g. if) but if you try and cast it to null it may fail because you cannot cast certain objects to bool.
4. you are not doing any assignment to any properties of $member so your output would never change

it seems like you want to do something like this:

```
$testarray = import-csv -path "C:directory\ocb2021\preprocessings.csv"
$Success=$false
# loop each object
foreach($member in $testarray)
{
  #matching condition
  if(($testarray -match $member.store).count -gt 1)
  {
    write-host  "match found"
    #indicate we had at least one match
    $Success=$true

    #change the value of the property "bar"
    $member.bar = $true
  }
}

if ($Success) {
   write-Host 'At least one match was found' -f Green
} else {
   write-host 'No matches were found!' -f Red
}

write-output $TestArray
```